# Error 404 - Not Found while configuration JEE with Keycloak in my web.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, keycloak

I'm working on a JEE project(using Maven, Jax-RS) running on Wildfly version 21. I need to secure my web-app(the front end will be in Angular) with Keycloak. I've created a realm, client and users, and created a keycloak.json file in WEB-INF.
The issue is that when I run my server without configurating the web.xml file it's all good, my server runs, the war in deployed and my api calls all work perfectly.
Now I want to configurate my project with Keycloak so I write these lines in my web.xml file:

```
<module-name>auth-proto-client</module-name>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>auth_prototype</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>


<login-config>
    <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    <realm-name>auth-proto-realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

The thing is when I put the `<security-constraint>`part, when I connect to my localhost I get 404- - Not Found. Can somebody tell me why is this happening?
Keycloak is running on port 8080, while I used  `-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1` to change the port for Wildfly.
EDIT:

### keycloak.json:

```
{
  "realm": "auth-proto-realm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "auth-proto-client",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "secret"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

### Stacktrace:

```
10:25:38,496 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.10.2.Final
10:25:43,744 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
10:25:43,779 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
10:25:44,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 21.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 13.0.1.Final) starting
10:25:46,497 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.13.1.Final
10:25:48,174 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
10:25:48,217 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
10:25:48,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:25:48,420 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.8.2.Final
10:25:48,434 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.2.Final
10:25:48,565 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
10:25:48,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:25:48,582 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
10:25:48,600 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
10:25:48,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:25:48,605 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.jwt.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYJWT0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile JWT Subsystem
10:25:48,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
10:25:48,613 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
10:25:48,628 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.23.Final)
10:25:48,633 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
10:25:48,654 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
10:25:48,694 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-00006
10:25:48,732 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
10:25:48,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
10:25:48,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
10:25:48,836 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.2.2.Final starting
10:25:48,878 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [com.mysql]"
10:25:48,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.13.2.Final
10:25:49,060 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
10:25:49,094 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:25:49,114 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Development\opt\application-server\wildfly-21.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
10:25:50,010 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 IO threads with 64 max task threads based on your 4 available processors
10:25:50,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
10:25:50,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
10:25:50,659 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.19.Final
10:25:50,710 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
10:25:50,712 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
10:25:50,905 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
10:25:51,012 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Development\opt\application-server\wildfly-21.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
10:25:51,026 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8081
10:25:51,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar")
10:25:51,073 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Development\opt\application-server\wildfly-21.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
10:25:51,199 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
10:25:51,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
mag 01, 2022 10:25:53 AM org.jboss.threads.Version <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
10:25:54,195 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8444
mag 01, 2022 10:25:54 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 5.0.19.Final
mag 01, 2022 10:25:54 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
10:25:54,446 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.4.2.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.7) 
INFO: XNIO version 3.8.2.Final
mag 01, 2022 10:25:54 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.2.Final
mag 01, 2022 10:25:55 AM org.wildfly.security.Version <clinit>
INFO: ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.13.1.Final
10:25:55,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver (version 8.0)
10:25:55,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar
10:25:55,256 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/auth_prototypeDS]
10:25:56,986 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Corona Extra' 11.0.4.Final
10:25:57,162 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
10:25:57,164 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
10:25:57,391 INFO  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.marshalling.InfinispanProtoStreamMarshaller'
10:25:57,829 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) WFLYCLINF0002: Started http-remoting-connector cache from ejb container
10:25:58,029 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar")
10:25:58,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
10:25:58,121 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 21.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 13.0.1.Final) started in 22245ms - Started 416 of 642 services (378 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
10:25:58,131 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9991/management
10:25:58,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9991
Connected to server
[2022-05-01 10:25:58,314] Artifact auth_prototype:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait…
10:25:58,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
10:26:07,430 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for auth_prototype
10:26:07,733 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
10:26:07,803 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#auth_prototype'
10:26:07,861 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: auth_prototype
    ...]
10:26:08,113 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.21.Final
10:26:08,187 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.18.Final}
10:26:08,190 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
10:26:08,810 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-5) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
10:26:08,881 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.5.Final}
10:26:09,013 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYRS0018: Explicit usage of Jackson annotation in a JAX-RS deployment; the system will disable JSON-B processing for the current deployment. Consider setting the 'resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB' property to 'false' to restore JSON-B.
10:26:09,114 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 3.1.5 (Final)
10:26:10,648 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#auth_prototype'
10:26:11,428 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
10:26:11,544 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) Envers integration enabled? : true
10:26:12,427 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
10:26:12,492 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) Hibernate: drop table if exists users
10:26:12,525 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=InnoDB
10:26:12,562 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
10:26:12,575 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) Hibernate: create table users (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), password varchar(255), username varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
10:26:12,732 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@24060bea'
10:26:12,924 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-4) MicroProfile: Metrics activated (SmallRye Metrics version: 2.4.2)
10:26:13,417 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 1) WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher is annotated with @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
10:26:14,506 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi, org.jboss.weld.api]
10:26:14,712 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi, org.jboss.weld.api]
10:26:14,974 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class it.lascaux.auth_prototype.rest.RestEndpoint$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
10:26:14,980 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DefaultNumberWriter is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,980 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.InputStreamProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,980 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,980 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ReaderProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,980 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,980 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.PatchMethodFilter is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,981 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.IIOImageProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,981 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DefaultTextPlain is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,981 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,981 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.JaxrsServerFormUrlEncodedProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,981 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.MultiValuedParamConverterProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,981 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.SourceProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,982 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.SseEventProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,982 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FileProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,982 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.JaxrsFormProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,982 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StreamingOutputProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:14,983 WARN  [org.jboss.as.weld] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYWELD0052: Using deployment classloader to load proxy classes for module com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider. Package-private access will not work. To fix this the module should declare dependencies on [org.jboss.weld.core, org.jboss.weld.spi, org.jboss.weld.api]
10:26:14,997 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.MessageSanitizerContainerResponseFilter is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,011 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.UnrecognizedPropertyExceptionHandler is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,011 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.sse.SseEventSinkInterceptor is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,011 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FileRangeWriter is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,011 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.AsyncStreamingOutputProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,011 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FormUrlEncodedProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,011 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DefaultBooleanWriter is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,011 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ByteArrayProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,011 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DataSourceProvider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
10:26:15,139 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth-proto-client' for server 'default-server'
10:26:15,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "auth_prototype-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
[2022-05-01 10:26:15,215] Artifact auth_prototype:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2022-05-01 10:26:15,215] Artifact auth_prototype:war: Deploy took 16,901 milliseconds
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please share your keycloak.json contents and whole stacktrace

Comment: I'll edit my question since it's complicated to read in the comment, thanks

Comment: where are the logs when you try to hit your http://localhost:8081/auth-proto-client URL (enable debug loggin for your application)? Also, what is your keycloak dependency version?

Comment: `Failed to load module for driver [com.mysql]` - that looks pretty important.  Have you tried to install the MySQL module?